# Print out object elements from list

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to print object element in my list with `foreach` loop in main scope, but the only thing that prints out is :

> ConsoleApplication1.WorldMap

What have gone wrong here and how do I get it to print out the actual elements?

```
using ConsoleApplication1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
     class WorldMap
     {

        private string higher;
        private string lower;

        public worldMap()
        {
        }

        public WorldMap(string higher, string lower)
        {
           this.higher = higher;
           this.lower = lower;
        } 

        public string Higher
        {
            get { return higher; }
            set { higher = value; }
        }

        public string Lower
        {
            get { return Lower; }
            set { Lower = value; }
        }
    }   
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        WorldMap map = new WorldMap();

        List<WorldMap> mapList = new List<WorldMap>();
        mapList.Add(new WorldMap(map.Lower, map.Higher));

        Console.WriteLine("\tInsert highest point:");
        map.Highest= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\tInsert lowest point");
        map.Lowest= Console.ReadLine();


        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\freq.txt", true))
        { 
            writer.WriteLine(map.Lower + map.Higher); 
        }

        foreach (object view in mapList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(view);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your answers! Nothing appears in the console but I'll check your answers once again.

Comment: Also do you know why nothing appears in the console? Because in this line `mapList.Add(new WorldMap(map.Lower, map.Higher));` the `map.Lower` and `map.Higher` are empty strings you should send a value for constructor like this: `mapList.Add(new WorldMap("lower", "higher"));`.

Comment: It works now, thanks! Used override and called the object in main by writeline. Which one of them is preferable in common enviroments? 


One step further...

Comment: I prefer the `override`.

Comment: So there's two options with 1 output, Console.WriteLine(map.ToString());
Is there any difference of using following? (map.Lower, map.Higher)); Or mapList.Add(new WorldMap("lower", "higher")); 





: mapList.Add(new WorldMap("lower", "higher"));.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't override the `ToString` method of `WorldMap` so `Console.WriteLine(view)` returns the name of the class which is `WorldMap`. You could either override the `ToString` method in the class or call the properties in the `foreach` loop but don't forget you should change `object` to `var`. Like this:

```
class WorldMap
{

   ....
   ....
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return Lower + " " + Higher;
   }
}
```

Or (*change `object` to `var`*):

```
foreach (var view in mapList)
{
     Console.WriteLine(view.Lower + " " + view.Higher);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view is of type WorldMap, Use it like this instead:

```
foreach (object view in mapList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(view.Lower.ToString() + "," + view.Higher.ToString() );
        }
```